# Recursive Menu Builder C#

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I need to build a breadscrum/ path for a course listing site

e.g Course has different menu items and i need to display then as below

- Chapter01/
- Chapter01/Lesson01/
- Chapter01/Lesson01/Exam01/
- Chapter01/Lesson01/Exam01/Question 03/
- Chapter01/Lesson01/Exam01/Question 04/Item 01
- Chapter01/Lesson02/
- Chapter02
- Chapter02/Lesson01

Above is just an example of how the items could get arranged in a path

In order to come up with this I have List of Items

```
Public Class Item
{
    public string Level
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The List can be create as below

```
IList<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
Items.Add (new Item {Level = "0", Title = "Chapter01"});
Items.Add (new Item {Level = "1", Title = "Lesson01"});
Items.Add (new Item {Level = "2", Title = "Exam01"});
Items.Add (new Item {Level = "3", Title = "Question 03"});
Items.Add (new Item {Level = "3", Title = "Question 04"});
Items.Add (new Item {Level = "4", Title = "Item 01"});
Items.Add (new Item {Level = "1", Title = "Lesson02"});

Items.Add (new Item {Level = "0", Title = "Chapter02"});
Items.Add (new Item {Level = "1", Title = "Lesson01"});
```

Parent item will always have the level as 0 and the children will have 1,2,3 etc...

Can anybody helm me to come up with a recursive function in C# to achieve this

Comment: Item class should have ID and Parent ID properties. So you know exactly which item comes under which item. Once you do that, post some code of what you tried.

Comment: Actually this objects doesn't have the id and parent id properties. It only has the level property. Level 0 is the parent node Level 1, is child of level 0 and level 2 is child of level 1 etc...

Comment: In your example you have 2 level zeroes. So Lesson01 goes under Chapter01 or Chapter02? Now your only option is to follow Duncan's idea.

Answer (score 2):

The way I last did this was to actually compose the menu items into a menu item. For example:

```
public class MenuItem{
    public string Caption {get; set;}
    public int Level {get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems {get; set;}
    public MenuItem(string caption){
        Caption = caption;
        MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
    }
}
```

Then when you build your menu structure, you start with a `List<MenuItem>` which will hold you top level MenuItem objects, and then `MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Question 1"))`.

When you have built up your hierarchy, you can then output it using something like:

```
private void DisplyMenuStructure(List<MenuItems> menu){
    foreach(MenuItem currentItem in menu){
        if (currentItem.MenuItems.Count>0){
            DisplayMenuStructure(currentItem.MenuItems);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine(currentItem.Caption);
        }
    }
}
```

To populate the hierarchy use something like this:

```
public void BuildMenumStructure(){
    //Instantiate a File menu
    MenuItem root = new MenuItem("File");
    root.Level = 0;
    //Add some menu items
    root.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("New"){Level = 1});
    root.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Edit"){Level = 1});
    //Build a save menu and add it in
    MenuItem saveMenu = new MenuItem("Save");
    saveMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Save As"){Level = 2});
    saveMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Save"){Level = 2});
    root.MenuItems.Add(saveMenu);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the post. hierarchy comes as I explained in my example. I am sorry I dont understand this code. Can u explain bit more ?

Comment: Effectively this class represents a menu option in your menu structure. If that menu option has child options, they are added into the parent items MenuItems property. If you wanted to add a level property to the class, that would be easy enough to do. I'll edit my code and repost it.